# Precise Definition of Span of a Set

Tags: linear-algebra

The following website gives the below definition of span https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span.

Given a vector space V over a field K, **the span of a set S of vectors (not necessarily finite) is defined to be the intersection W of all subspaces of V that contain S.** W is referred to as the subspace spanned by S, or by the vectors in S. Conversely, S is called a spanning set of W, and we say that S spans W.

I am symbolically trying to write in this form as a definition of  [span](https://books.google.com/books?id=v1syL6ZODMEC&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=intersection%20and%20definition%20of%20span&source=bl&ots=ZJ5LFObwb6&sig=TfNTgH28CKKToRRzreMnSiGg7Co&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0vIvlz_DTAhVB5CYKHTAIAcEQ6AEIeDAR#v=onepage&q=intersection%20and%20definition%20of%20span&f=false), but I do not like how they label S as a subspace of V in the definition.

- Would this modification be an appropriate definition for span (S)?

  Let S, V, and F be sets where V is a Vector space over a field F. The
  $span(S)= \bigcap_{A\subseteq M\subseteq V}M$ where $A=S\cap V$ .

Comment: $S \subset V$ so $S \cap V = S$. The other way to think of the span is that it's the set of all finite linear combinations of elements in $S$. Proving the equivalence of the two definitions will be enlightening.

Comment: $\mathrm{Span}(S) = \bigcap\{ M\leq V\mid M\text{ is a subspace and }S\subseteq M\}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Nice to see you here again!!

Comment: Does S have to be a subset of V though (not based off that definition but in general)? I am curious of the case where S is not a subset of V which is why I have the intersection for A as such. Also, I am not sure if you can apply the definition of span to different levels of infinity when you say M is less than or equal to V which is what I am wanting to do. That's if you are referring to the cardinalities of M and V.

Comment: @Will  If $V$ is your vector space what does it mean for $S$ to not be a subset? Where are the elements of $S$ coming from?

Comment: I am curious if S can even live outside V. Why would S have to be affiliated with V?

Comment: What would be the point of talking about the span of $S$ if $S$ is not a subset of $V$?

Comment: I am curious if this definition is accurate not necessarily what the point of it is.

Comment: The definition is never used except in the context in which $S$ is a subset of $V$. The question (and definition) are nonsensical otherwise.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. Please post in the answer box if you would like credit.